# Dynamic SQL Pivot (with CONVERT DateField

Tags: mysql, sql, pivot

I'm trying to do a pivot which I have managed to do on the below code only using (date_time_hour).

However as I need to return my date value by yyy-dd-mm I have been using:

```
CONVERT(CHAR(10),tz_date_hour, 20)
```

When I use it in the below I'm unable to return the correct values.

[image: SQL Code sample]

I thought it would be something like:

```
SET @sql = N'SELECT *
FROM (
        SELECT ivr_reason,' +  
CONVERT(CHAR(10),tz_date_hour, 20) + ', total_usage
FROM [Genesys_var].[dbo].[app_subcf_results2]) AS D

PIVOT(MAX(total_usage) FOR tz_date_hour IN(' + @cols + N')) AS P;';

EXEC sp_executesql @sql;
GO
```

But it doesn't seem to work any I can't find anything related.

Comment: What error you receive?

Comment: Which RDBMS is this for? Please add a tag to specify whether you're using `mysql`, `postgresql`, `sql-server`, `oracle` or `db2` - or something else entirely.

Comment: Hi, i it just displays it as the below.   tz_date_hour not found   http://i.imgur.com/VAzvSiX.png

Comment: Check my answer, It should work for you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't need to use `+` in select clause. Should be something like this:

```
SET @sql = N'SELECT *
FROM (
        SELECT ivr_reason,  
               CONVERT(CHAR(10),tz_date_hour, 20) AS tz_date_hour, 
               total_usage
        FROM [Genesys_var].[dbo].[app_subcf_results2]
      ) AS D

PIVOT(MAX(total_usage) FOR tz_date_hour IN(' + @cols + N')) AS P;';

EXEC sp_executesql @sql;
GO
```