# pivot to change rows to columns on all values held in the column

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have tried getting this working but haven't had any success. I am trying to get this this working on SQL Server where the rows are converted to columns. Here is the SQL:

```
 select *
   (
    select foldername, prcIncidentManagement.CallCategory
    from prcIncidentManagement
   )
   pivot
   (
    count(foldername)
    for prcIncidentManagement.CallCategory in ('Software','Hardware'.etc..)
   )
```

The actual `CallCategory` field had more than 20 values. Is there any way of dynamically selecting all *, without predefining it if a new value gets added.

Thank you.

Comment: lot of dynamic pivots examples are there in stack over flow ..just do the perfect search

Comment: There are lot of answers... There are at least 4 answers where I have posted about dynamic pivot:

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32346362/t-sql-pivot-table-selecting-for-in
or
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30612546/flip-sql-result
or 
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29430138/dynamic-sql-pivot-with-convert-datefield
or
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32755751/pivot-dynamic-row-to-column-with-output-parameter

Comment: Which dbms are you using? Pivot support can be very different for some of them.

Comment: @jarlh as OP said `I am trying to get this this working on SQL Server `